# Remove everything in a string after the first " - " (multiple " - ")

Tags: r, regex

I am struggling to only keep the part before the first " - ".
If I try this regex on regex101.com I get the expected output but when I try it in R I get a different output.

```
authors <- sub("\\s-\\s.*", "", authors)
```

Input:

```
[1] "T Dietz, RL Shwom, CT Whitley - Annual Review of Sociology, 2020 - annualreviews.org"         
[2] "L Berrang-Ford, JD Ford, J Paterson - Global environmental change, 2011 - Elsevier"           
[3] "CD Thomas - Diversity and Distributions, 2010 - Wiley Online Library"
```

Expected output:

```
 [1] "T Dietz, RL Shwom, CT Whitley"       
 [2] "L Berrang-Ford, JD Ford, J Paterson"
 [3] "CD Thomas"
```

Actual output:

```
 [1] "T Dietz, RL Shwom, CT Whitley - Annual Review of Sociology, 2020"       
 [2] "L Berrang-Ford, JD Ford, J Paterson - Global environmental change, 2011"
 [3] "CD Thomas - Diversity and Distributions, 2010"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you receive output containing some Unicode whitespaces.

In this case, the following will work:

```r
sub("(*UTF)(*UCP)\\s-\\s.*", "", authors, perl=TRUE)
```

The `(*UTF)(*UCP)` (or probably just `(*UCP)`) will enable `\s` to match any Unicode whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex. Replace for nothing the result in Notepad++ for example:

#### Regex

```
 -(.*?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment at the moment, may delete later. When I run this code alone, I get your expected output:

```r
authors <- c("T Dietz, RL Shwom, CT Whitley - Annual Review of Sociology, 2020 - annualreviews.org",      
"L Berrang-Ford, JD Ford, J Paterson - Global environmental change, 2011 - Elsevier",           
"CD Thomas - Diversity and Distributions, 2010 - Wiley Online Library")

sub("\\s-\\s.*", "", authors)

#[1] "T Dietz, RL Shwom, CT Whitley"       "L Berrang-Ford, JD Ford, J Paterson" "CD Thomas"
```

This might have something to do with the fact that you reassign to authors every time you try subbing, which overwrites authors. You might have been doing that as you were developing the regex, and forgot to reassign the authors vector to the original.

Comment: It indeed works the way you do it. But for some weird reason it doesn't work when I do the following:                                                                                                               
**authors <- html_text(authors_nodes, trim=TRUE)**           
and then **authors_stripped <- sub("\\s-\\s.*", "", authors)**

Comment: Can you give us the contents of `author_nodes` and the authors that comes after the first step. Or better, all of your code relevant here?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just split the string on your delimiter (`-`) and take the first element:

```
sapply(strsplit(authors, " -", fixed = T), `[[`, 1)
[1] "T Dietz, RL Shwom, CT Whitley"       "L Berrang-Ford, JD Ford, J Paterson"
[3] "CD Thomas"
```

You can also use regex greedy matching to remove everything after and including your delimiter. Because it is greedy it will match as much as possible:

```
stringr::str_remove(authors, " -.*")
[1] "T Dietz, RL Shwom, CT Whitley"       "L Berrang-Ford, JD Ford, J Paterson"
[3] "CD Thomas"
```